Using DataBindings to update a label but it not working (C# Winform)
I'm learning C# recently. Here is a simple program I created to try out the functionality of DataBindings. I was hoping that it would work but no, every time btnAdd and btnMinus are clicked, the value in lbData remains unchanged.
What error am I making? Thank you if you took the time to respond to this question.
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace Test
{
    public class GetData
    {
        private int _data;
        public int Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set
            {
                _data = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Data");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public GetData(int data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }


    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public GetData _data = new GetData(10);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lbData.DataBindings.Add("Text", _data, "Data");
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _data.Data++;
        }

        private void btnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _data.Data--;
        }
    }
}

Actually, I didn't find out where I needed to fix it. Besides, there weren't any errors in the compiler. Looking forward to all the helpers.

You should be implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Without that, the Binding doesn't know to look for the change event.

You're missing a couple of pieces. Follow the pattern described here (first method). Read the notes in the introduction
